# Discontinuities of $u'$ where $u \in W^{1, \infty}([0, T])$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I was having a closer look at the Sobolev space $W^{1, \infty}([0, T])$. I was wondering if $u'$ has a representative that is continuous a.e.. I know that $W^{1, \infty}([0, T]) \hookrightarrow C([0, T])$, but does that tell me anything about the derivatives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v = u'$ can be any bounded measurable function, your question is equivalent to asking if every bounded measurable function $v$ has a representative that is continuous a.e.  The answer is certainly no; one counterexample is $v = 1_C$ where $C$ is a "fat Cantor set" which is nowhere dense but has positive measure.  If $w = v$ a.e. then the set where $w=0$ is still dense, and the set where $w=1$ still has positive measure, so $w$ is discontinuous at every point of that set.

Comment: But can it be every bounded measurable function though? What would, speaking in your example, be $u$ such that $u' = v$?

Comment: @Meowdog: $u(t) = \int_0^t v\,dm$.  That's the fundamental theorem of calculus (Lebesgue measure version).

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you